# Two columns landscape or portrait

Tags: formatting

I understand that LaTeX doesn't use the full width of the page because narrower text is easier to read. Although I would like to utilise most of the available area. Therefore I decided to have my text in two columns.

Is it better to have it in two columns in landscape orientation or portrait?

Landscape seems to produce text width closer to suggested, but all articles I read are printed in portrait.

Comment: In most situations, portrait will be the most readable format. Landscape text in two column is difficult to read. I know, because many law firms are using this format for different due diligence reports. Probably introduced by consultants using Powerpoint as their word processor.

Comment: for typical paper sizes, two columns in landscape has the same problem as one column in portrait that the text width is too wide unless you have large margins, so it would not help your stated problem at all I think.

Comment: Landscape books are often difficult to handle while reading. A single landscape sheet is less problematic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the output on a laptop where the screen is wider than it is tall, you can use the following code to avoid scrolling. The landscape columns are quite easy to read. You could also use multiple columns for newspaper column output like the discontinued Stanza reader program or the Tofu program for Mac:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}       
\geometry{landscape}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2.cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\lipsum{10}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

If you want only two columns, use `\begin{multicols}{2}` and `\end{multicols}`.